# Dual intent Canada, TRV and PR thru PNP

Tags: canada, paperwork

I am applying for a study permit in Canada, and I want to use the same opportunity to apply for permanent residence thru PNP.

If I apply and get my study permit approved, can I in turn, apply for permanent residence through PNP programs through a province? Or can I apply for PR thru PNP independently, without the need for PGWP?

Comment: Would you have enough points through education and experience to qualify for a PNP without the degree you're planning to get?

Comment: Seems that the question has been abandoned...